# Enable SSL (HTTPS) on Bitnami MEAN setup on AWS

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, https, mean-stack, bitnami

I use a Bitnami MEAN installation (https://bitnami.com/stack/mean) v 3.2.11 on EC2. I didn't do any extra modifications of the apache2 setup except for the rerouting the port where my app runs to port 80, like this

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

Now my app is available fine on `:80` port via `http://` but I can't make it run via `https://`. But access via https is what I wanted to achieve. I could not figure the right step by step guide on how to create or enable SSL. All Bitnami docs sound like it's assumed to be working already.

As far as I understood from - https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/apache/#https-port the basic certificate is already included into the setup so you can make use of that one without creating your own. The only thing you need is to enable it - **That may be wrong assumption, let me know.**

Also [here on bitnami support](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/apache/#https-port) it says

> Apache waits for HTTPS requests on port 443. Change that by editing
>   the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf file and modifying
>   the value specified in the Port directive. For example:
>
> Listen 8443

Does that mean that I need to reroute my :5000 port to :8443 ??

I've also found this question - [Installing SSL on AWS EC2 Bitnami Mean Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309162/installing-ssl-on-aws-ec2-bitnami-mean-stack) that didn't recieve a proper answer for more than a year.

Answer (score 0):

> Does that mean that I need to reroute my :5000 port to :8443 ??

No, you don't need to redirect that. Your problem is that you're proxy-passing every request from port 80 to 5000 (where your app runs) but when using HTTPS your requests use the port 443. Those request are not being proxy-passed to port 5000 and, therefore, your app doesn't receive them.

What Apache configuration file did you modify including those lines? You need to be sure that both the VirtualHosts for port 80 and the one for port 443 include the `ProxyPass` redirections. For example, if you edited the file `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf`, ensure you add it in the Virtualhosts `<VirtualHost _default_:80>` and `<VirtualHost _default_:443>`

> As far as I understood from - https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/apache/#https-port the basic certificate is already included into the setup so you can make use of that one without creating your own.

Yes, the Bitnami Stack includes a dummy certificate. However, it's recommended to create your own one since the browsers won't recognize it as a valid one since it's self-signed. You can find more information in the link below:

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/apache/#how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate

Comment: I used this guide - https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/nodejs/#how-to-create-a-custom-nodejs-application so I've created a subfolder in /opt/bitnami/apps/ etc. then some files in ti and latter included a link to into ```/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf```

Comment: I'll try to go through the steps you've referenced on creating you own certificate